# Getting rails3-autocomplete-jquery gem to work nicely with Simple_Form with multiple inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

So I am trying to implement multiple autocomplete using [this gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/) and simple_form and am getting an error.

I tried this:

```
<%= f.input_field :neighborhood_id, collection: Neighborhood.order(:name), :url => autocomplete_neighborhood_name_searches_path, :as => :autocomplete, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :class => "span8" %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `to_i' for ["Alley Park, Madison"]:Array
```

In my params, it is sending this in `neighborhood_id`:

```
"search"=>{"neighborhood_id"=>["Alley Park, Madison"],
```

So it isn't even using the IDs for those values.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Edit 1:**

In response to @jvnill's question, I am not explicitly doing anything with `params[:search]` in the controller. A search creates a new record, and is searching `listings`.

In my Searches Controller, `create` action, I am simply doing this:

```
@search = Search.create!(params[:search])
```

Then my `search.rb` (i.e. search model) has this:

```
def listings
    @listings ||= find_listings
end

private
  def find_listings
    key = "%#{keywords}%"
    listings = Listing.order(:headline)
    listings = listings.includes(:neighborhood).where("listings.headline like ? or neighborhoods.name like ?", key, key) if keywords.present?
    listings = listings.where(neighborhood_id: neighborhood_id) if neighborhood_id.present?
    #truncated for brevity
    listings
  end
```

Comment: have you performed `bundle` after adding to Gemfile.

Comment: Yes. The gem was installed properly, because I am using the `autocomplete` functionality on some other fields elsewhere and it works perfectly. Also, the autocomplete functionality works on this field - it's just the multiple functionality is not working.

Comment: can you include part of the controller code where you are using `params[:search][:neighborhood_id]`

Comment: `Search.create!(params[:search])` uses neighborhood_id which is an array from the params.  This is what's causing your error.  how do you plan to save the multiple neighborhood to the database? or is that part of your requirements?

Comment: Well....I would love suggestions on how to achieve that :) The desired result is that I want to be able to query multiple `neighborhood_ids` with 1 search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this would be easier if the form is returning the ids instead of the name of the neighborhood. I haven't used the gem yet so I'm not familiar how it works.  Reading on the readme says that it will return ids but i don't know why you're only getting names.  I'm sure once you figure out how to return the ids, you'll be able to change the code below to suit that.

You need to create a join table between a neighborhood and a search. Let's call that search_neighborhoods.

```
rails g model search_neighborhood neighborhood_id:integer search_id:integer
# dont forget to add indexes in the migration
```

After that, you'd want to setup your models.

```
# search.rb
has_many :search_neighborhoods
has_many :neighborhoods, through: :search_neighborhoods

# search_neighborhood.rb
belongs_to :search
belongs_to :neighborhood

# neighborhood.rb
has_many :search_neighborhoods
has_many :searches, through: :search_neighborhoods
```

Now that we've setup the associations, we need to setup the setters and the attributes

```
# search.rb
attr_accessible :neighborhood_names

# this will return a list of neighborhood names which is usefull with prepopulating
def neighborhood_names
  neighborhoods.map(&:name).join(',')
end

# we will use this to find the ids of the neighborhoods given their names
# this will be called when you call create!
def neighborhood_names=(names)
  names.split(',').each do |name|
    next if name.blank?
    if neighborhood = Neighborhood.find_by_name(name)
      search_neighborhoods.build neighborhood_id: neighborhood.id
    end
  end
end

# view
# you need to change your autocomplete to use the getter method
<%= f.input :neighborhood_names, url: autocomplete_neighborhood_name_searches_path, as: :autocomplete, input_html: { data: { delimiter: ',', multiple: true, class: "span8" } %>
```

last but not the least is to update `find_listings`

```
def find_listings
  key = "%#{keywords}%"
  listings = Listing.order(:headline).includes(:neighborhood)

  if keywords.present?
    listings = listings.where("listings.headline LIKE :key OR neighborhoods.name LIKE :key", { key: "#{keywords}")
  end

  if neighborhoods.exists?
    listings = listings.where(neighborhood_id: neighborhood_ids)
  end

  listings
end
```

And that's it :)

UPDATE: using f.input_field

```
# view
<%= f.input_field :neighborhood_names, url: autocomplete_neighborhood_name_searches_path, as: :autocomplete, data: { delimiter: ',' }, multiple: true, class: "span8" %>

# model
# we need to put [0] because it returns an array with a single element containing
# the string of comma separated neighborhoods
def neighborhood_names=(names)
  names[0].split(',').each do |name|
    next if name.blank?
    if neighborhood = Neighborhood.find_by_name(name)
      search_neighborhoods.build neighborhood_id: neighborhood.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know why I have a feeling that once I figure out how to get it to send the IDs, it will work without having to setup this join table and do all of this.

Comment: no, you still need to setup a join table if you're able to send the ids since you want to work with multiple neighborhoods for a single search.  if you don't want to setup a join table, you can look at saving the ids in a text column that is serialized.

Comment: Hrmm...ok...how can I test this without using this - to see if your solution works for me? I can't get a response from the gem creators about this issue - so not sure if I can get it to send IDs and I have tried everything I can think of (and what others recommend too).

Comment: Ok...this is progress, the issue is that while the params neighborhood_names is right, the ID is not - Parameters: `{"search"=>{"neighborhood_names"=>["Alley Park,Madison,"], "num_bedrooms"=>"", "num_bathrooms"=>"", "min_price"=>"", "max_price"=>"", "boro_id"=>"", "property_type_id"=>""}}`. 

`INSERT INTO "searches" ("neighborhood_id", "num_bathrooms", "num_bedrooms", "property_type_id") VALUES ($8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["neighborhood_id", nil], ["num_bathrooms", nil], ["num_bedrooms", nil], ["property_type_id", nil]]`

Comment: ok can you give me a minute. i'm trying to put up a sample app

Comment: If you get it working, if you can push it to Github, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: ok here it is. https://github.com/jvnill/simple_form_search_app. also updated my answer

Comment: Perfect...one little issue with this. You changed the `f.input_field` to `f.input`. The reason I changed it to `input_field` is because of the formatting. It adds 2 wrapper divs around the input as `f.input` as opposed to just giving you the `<input>` for `f.input_field`. However, when I change it to `input_field`, the `class: span8` is not applied to the input. Do you find that in your implementation? i.e. if I change it back to `f.input_field` the multiple option doesn't work. But I need `f.input_field` for my layout to not break.

Comment: So with `f.input_field` I can't select more than 1 option with the syntax you provided. How do I get `f.input_field` to work with multiple selections and a comma separated delimiter like you have in your code?

Comment: Now the multiple select works, but I am back to the original error - `undefined method 'to_i' for ["Hudson Heights,Upper West Side,"]:Array`  *sigh* :( Do I need to change `listings = listings.where(neighborhood_id: neighborhood_ids)` in the `find_listings`?

Comment: sorry that should be neighborhood_names, not neighborhood_id on the updated code

Comment: YES!!! Perfect. That did it. Thank you kind sir. You, sir....deserve the entire bounty and more. I really appreciate your patience and your full answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you're collecting values from the neighborhood Model

```
 Neighborhood.order(:name)
```

will return an array of names, you need to also collect the id, but just display the names
use collect and pass a block, I beleive this might owrk for you

```
Neighborhood.collect {|n| [n.name, n.id]}
```

Declare a scope on the Neighborhood class to order it by name if you like to get theat functionality back, as that behavior also belongs in the model anyhow.

edit>
To add a scope/class method to neighborhood model, you'd typically do soemthing like this

```
scope :desc, where("name DESC")
```

Than you can write something like:

```
Neighborhood.desc.all
```

which will return an array, thus allowing the .collect but there are other way to get those name and id attributes recognized by the select option.

Comment: If I declared a scope, how would I use it in that `collect` block? `Neighborhood.ordered.collect ...`?

Comment: Btw, that doesn't work. I get this error: `undefined method 'collect' for #<Class:0x007fd05a383c18>`. Remember that the `collection` attribute in that simple_form helper call is expecting an array of names.

Comment: Very true, can't call collect on an ActiveRecord relation, my apologizies for got the .all, Neighborhood.all returns an array, Neighborhood.order("name DESC") should return an array also.

Comment: Nope...that doesn't work. The scope was wrong, it should actually be: `scope :desc, order("name DESC")`. And, I tried `Neighborhood.desc.all.collect {|n| [n.name, n.id]}` and it gave me the same error - which is `undefined method 'to_i' for ["Madison,Alley Park,"]:Array` Thoughts?