# Using partials, how do I render `striped` table rows in a DRY way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

So I have some view code that looks like this:

```
<div class="box-content">
    <table class="table table-properties">
        <tbody>             
            <%= render :partial => 'property', collection: @search.listings, as: :listing %>
        </tbody>
    </table>                                
</div>
```

In that `_property.html.erb`, I have this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="span2">
        <%= link_to listing_path(listing), :class => "thumbnail thumb2" do %>
            <%= image_tag "room_1.jpg", :alt => "Lucas" %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h2><%= link_to listing.headline, listing_path(listing) %></h2>
        <h5><%= listing.listing_type.name if listing.listing_type "#{listing.neighborhood.name.capitalize}" %></h5>
        <h5>Maintenance <%= number_to_currency(listing.maintenance) %></h5>
    </td>
    <td class="span1">
        <h2 class="price"><%= number_to_currency(listing.price)%></h2>
        <h5><%= "#{listing.num_bedrooms} bed, #{listing.num_bathrooms} bath" %></h5>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Basically, I want to generate that above code exactly, for each row, the only difference is I want every 2nd row (i.e. all even numbered rows) to have the `class=striped`..i.e. `<tr class=striped>`.

Thoughts on how to do this in a DRY way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried using `cycle` and `current_cycle` ?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle

```
<tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') -%>">
  <!-- etc -->
</tr>
```

This alternates your classes with `odd` and `even` and IMHO should also work when render a collection. If you need the value of the actual cycle multiple times, you get it with `current_cycle` (because calling `cycle` multiple times would mess up your cycles, unless you want that).

Comment: This is perfect, I have used this before and couldn't remember what it was called. Do you happen to have any experience with simple_form? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872162/getting-rails3-autocomplete-jquery-gem-to-work-nicely-with-simple-form-with-mult

Comment: glad I could help. sorry, don't know simple form.

Answer (score 1):

Won't it be better just to use `:nth-child()` css selector? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Nah, I prefer using the `cycle` helper indicated by the others.

Comment: I would prefer :nth-child, but support for IE8 is still important for most of my projects. `cycle` allows for bulletproof styling for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 <tr class="<%=cycle("odd", "even") %>">
    <td class="span2">
        <%= link_to listing_path(listing), :class => "thumbnail thumb2" do %>
            <%= image_tag "room_1.jpg", :alt => "Lucas" %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h2><%= link_to listing.headline, listing_path(listing) %></h2>
        <h5><%= listing.listing_type.name if listing.listing_type "#{listing.neighborhood.name.capitalize}" %></h5>
        <h5>Maintenance <%= number_to_currency(listing.maintenance) %></h5>
    </td>
    <td class="span1">
        <h2 class="price"><%= number_to_currency(listing.price)%></h2>
        <h5><%= "#{listing.num_bedrooms} bed, #{listing.num_bathrooms} bath" %></h5>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks much for this. I have used this before, but forgot the name of this helper method. Btw, do you have any experience with Simple_Form - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872162/getting-rails3-autocomplete-jquery-gem-to-work-nicely-with-simple-form-with-mult ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table.table-properties > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
   $("table.table-properties > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");  
});
```

Comment: Too heavy. I like the rails helper approach - just using `cycle` as the helper in my `tr class` is very sexy...imho.